# Filtering list_filter in Django admin based on field in foreign key

Tags: django, django-admin

I would like to filter one of my list_filters by a field in the table that the foreign key points to.

My models:

```
class Organisation(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    COMPANY = 'COMPANY'
    CHARITY = 'CHARITY'
    ORG_CHOICES = (
        (COMPANY, 'COMPANY'),
        (CHARITY, 'CHARITY'),
        )
    type = models.CharField(choices = ORG_CHOICES)

class Issue(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField
   charity = models.ForeignKey(Organisation)
```

I would like to put in IssueAdmin:

```
list_filter = (charity)
```

And for that to supply a list of charities.  Currently it just lists everything in the organisation model, both the charities and the companies.  For example I get this list in the filter at the moment:

```
oxfam
yamaha
greenpeace
microsoft
```

When I want a filter that lists:

```
oxfam
greenpeace
```

I could fix this by splitting the organisation table into two tables (charity and company) but that feels wrong.

It seems like SimpleListFilter should work, but I've not had any luck so far.  Basically I would like something the uses the following filter and returns a list of charities for the filter:

```
Organisation.objects.filter(type = 'CHARITY')
```

My (poor) attempt at a filter:

```
class CharityFilter(SimpleListFilter):
    title = _('Charity')
    parameter = _('charity__type')
    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        return Organisation.objects.filter(type = 'CHARITY')

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        if not self.value() is not None:
            return queryset.filter(type = 'CHARITY')
        else:
            return queryset
```

Can any one help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I'm getting it right you're trying to filter Issue instances not by the type of the Organization they belong to, but by the Organization instances themselves, so you will have on the right a potentially very long list of Organizations to filter Issues on, but you want only CHARITies to appear in this list.

This may not be the best solution if there are many Organizations, but only if they're few...

Anyway, as per the Django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/ the lookups() method of a Filter must return a list of tuple (coded_value,displayed_value).

The following untested code should work in your case:

```
class CharityFilter(SimpleListFilter):
    title = _('Charity')
    parameter_name = 'charity'
    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        queryset = model_admin.queryset(request).filter(organisation__type='CHARITY')
        return queryset.values_list('organisation__pk','organisation__name').order_by('organisation__name')

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        if self.value():
          return queryset.filter(organisation=self.value())
```

Comment: That worked.  I had to add .distinct() to the end of the return in the lookups, otherwise it listed the same charity 100s of times.  But otherwise, it works perfectly.  Thanks.

Comment: Still works well, thanks! But for anyone using a modern version of django- change model_admin.queryset to model_admin.get_queryset

Comment: `Unresolved reference '_'` fo line `title = _('Charity') `in your code

Answer (score 6):

Why don't you just filter on the type, ie:

```
class OrganisationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = ("type", )
    # etc
```

It would allow you to have either all organisations, companies only or charities only.

Else if you realy want to treat "Charities" and "Companies" as distinct entities with distinct admins but still keep them in the same table, you can use proxy models, but I don't see the point here.

Edit : to filter `issues` based on organization type it works just the same as with querying on relayed models (not a surprise since it's exactly what happens)

```
class IssueAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter =("charity__type", )
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer, I'm trying to do this in IssueAdmin.  If it were in OrganisationAdmin, what you suggest would work.

Comment: That just allows me to filter between charities and companies.  That is not what I'm trying to do.  When I put 'charity' into the list_filter, it gives me a list of the names of the all the entries in the organisations model in the filter.  So the list includes 'oxfam', 'greenpeace', 'Microsoft'.  I just want it to show 'oxfam' and 'greenpeace'.

Comment: I have updated the question, as I've obviously not explained what I want to do well.  Sorry about that.

Comment: I'd like to go your second route `list_filter =("organisation__type", )`. 1. Why is it `"organisation__type"` and not `"charity__type"`? (the field name is `charity`, `Organisation` is the model name). 2. If I try either I'd get `<class 'IssueAdmin'>: (admin.E116) The value of 'list_filter[0]' refers to 'charity__type', which does not refer to a Field.`. How can overcome this?

Comment: @CsabaToth 1/ was a typo (corrected). 2/ post a question with a proper [mcve] then - I've been using this for years and it always worked as expected so far. Just note that my answer above doesn't really address the OP's question in it's final form (the OP edited the question after I posted this).

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers maybe it's that I use Django 1.11 and it doesn't work with that yet? I'll open up a question later.

Comment: @CsabaToth As I said: post a question with a proper  [mcve]. The usage I describe has been supported for years (actually since the 1.3 release https://django.readthedocs.io/en/1.3.X/ref/contrib/admin/index.html#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter) so if it "doesn't work" for you you must be doing something wrong one way or another...