# Django: add a list filter option to filter related models under parent model

Tags: python, django

I would like to request assistance in this matter

I have the following models:

```
class Job(models.Model):
    Job_Position = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, unique=True)

class Job_Posting(models.Model):
    fkey = models.ForeignKey("Job", verbose_name="Job Positions", unique=True)
```

and Admin:

```
class jobs(admin.TabularInline): 
    model = Job_Posting
    readonly_fields = [ 'fkey',]
    extra = 0

class applicant(admin.ModelAdmin):

    model = Job
    list_display = ('Job_Position')
    list_filter = ['Job_Position']
    inlines = [jobs]
```

Is it possible to add a list filter option from inline? Something like this `list_filter = ['Job_Position', 'Job_Posting.fkey']` or for example, the current `list_filter` I have shows all items under `Job_Position`(selecting a `Job_Position` shows all record that have that position) and I want to add another option filtering all `Job_Position` that have that specific `Job_Posting.fkey` while giving me an option to see all the records

Can you do this or it's not just possible? or if there are other options what would it be? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

I need something like [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter), filtering all `Job` that has that `Job_Posting`, `fkey` in list_filter

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django admin, filter objects for inline formset](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101979/django-admin-filter-objects-for-inline-formset)

Comment: It doesn't give me the option to see all the records just like the default `list_filter`. what I basically what to do is to add another `list_filter` option that gets all the applicant record that have the specific `fkey`, sorry if my post is a bit messy, I'll add an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found what I am looking for [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20149337/filtering-list-filter-in-django-admin-based-on-field-in-foreign-key), to filter `Job` through `Job_Posting fkey`, I just need to add `Job_Posting__fkey` in my `list_filter` looking like this:

```
class applicant(admin.ModelAdmin):

    model = Job
    list_display = ('Job_Position')
    list_filter = ['Job_Position', 'Job_Posting__fkey']
    inlines = [jobs]
```